# Is there a method to convert the Django ORM queryset to Raw SQL to include the select_related and prefetch_related?

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-orm

How does the Django ORM query with select_related and prefetch_related convert to raw SQL?

I have a Django ORM query which I have tried to convert to Raw SQL but the prefetch related does not work.

```
data = table1.objects.filter(
            is_deleted=False)\
            .select_related('created_by', 'location')\
            .prefetch_related(
              'table2',
              'table3'
            )
raw_query = str(data.query)
```

The raw query does not contain from prefetch related. Is this the correct process?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the generated raw query simply print that query like this:

```
print(data.query)
```